# Group bar chart by another column in plotly (R)

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

How can I get a bar chart grouped by State using R in plotly?

My desired result should like this sample chart made in excel: [image: Click here for image]

My data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  State = c(
    "Tennessee", "Tennessee", "Tennessee", "Tennessee",
    "Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Kentucky",
    "Georgia", "Georgia", "Georgia"
  ),
  City = c(
    "Chattanooga", "Knoxville", "Memphis", "Nashville",
    "Covington", "Owensboro", "Bowling Green", "Lexington", "Louisville",
    "Columbus City", "Augusta", "Atlanta City"
  ),
  Population = c(
    177571, 186239, 652717, 660388,
    40640, 57265, 58067, 295803, 597337,
    189885, 195844, 420033
  )
)
```

My code:

```
plot_ly(data) %>%
  add_trace(
    x = ~City,
    y = ~Population,
    type = 'bar',
    name = 'Population')
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ggplot`:

```
data <- data.frame(State, City, Population)
colnames(data)<-c("category","subcategory","population")

ggplot(data, aes(category, population)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = category, color=subcategory), position = "dodge", stat="identity")+
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(rep("white", 17))) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image: ggplot2 solution]

and, using `ggplotly`:

```
ggplotly()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using ggplot or ggplotly? This is in a shinyapp with a lot of other charts and I need to be able to use the same design as the other charts that are just made using plotly. Also, is there any way to fix the spacing?

Answer (score 1):

A pure plotly solution may look like so. With different subcatgories you have to use subplots:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(State = factor(State, levels = c("Tennessee", "Kentucky", "Georgia"))) %>% 
  split(.$State) %>% 
  purrr::imap(function(x, y) {
    mutate(x, City = reorder(City, Population)) %>% 
      plot_ly() %>%
      add_bars(x = ~City,
               y = ~Population,
               color = ~State,
               colors = c(Tennessee = '#1f77b4',  # muted blue
                          Kentucky = '#ff7f0e',  # safety orange
                          Georgia = '#2ca02c'  # cooked asparagus green"
               )) %>% 
      layout(xaxis = list(tickvals = (nrow(x) -1) / 2, ticktext = y))}
    ) %>%
  subplot(shareY = TRUE)
```

[image]